# Rails: Unable to route to edit page when a new nested item fails validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, routes

I have a nested item whose creation form lies in the show view of its parent. In this case it is a single achievement (achievement_item) on an achievements list (achievement).

Everything seems to work except for *new* items that fail validation. An error is thrown up:

> **Routing Error**
>
> `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"achievements"}`
>
> Try running `rake routes` for more information on available routes.

When I run `rake routes` I get a forest of information. As an aside, what specifically should I be looking for? I compared the "show" actions of achievements and achievement_items to their counterparts in photo_galleries and gallery_photos (a structure I got working - it redirects invalid new gallery_photos to the edit page - I've been comparing all of the files side by side, but I haven't found any logical differences, which isn't to say that there aren't any), but everything looks like it has the same format.

I don't even know where to begin. This is what I'm going for in the controller of the nested item:

```
def create
    @achievement = Achievement.find(params[:achievement_id])
    @achievement_item = @achievement.achievement_items.create(params[:achievement_item])
    if @achievement_item.save
        redirect_to achievement_path(@achievement)
    else
        render "edit"
    end
end
```

Commenting out `render "edit"` causes a missing template error, so at least I know I'm hitting this line.

Here is my edit page:

```
<h1>Editing achievement item</h1>

<%= render 'form', achievement_item: @achievement_item %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @achievement %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', achievement_path %>
```

It would be really nice if such an error message would point you toward where the problem is. And [Somebody Should Do Something About All the Problems](http://www.theonion.com/articles/somebody-should-do-something-about-all-the-problem,11018/). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banging out the question made me find the answer. In the hopes that this saves *somebody* a few hours of frustration, here it is:

In the edit page of the nested item:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', achievements_path %>
```

That's it. *A missing plural on a link I wasn't even really using led to hours of frustration*.

Comment: So often the way!  Please mark this as the answer so people know you've solved it.

Comment: Totally would have. "You can accept your own answer in two days," it said. :-) Thanks for the encouragement.